# Voice mail text: "Please leave a message after the..."

Tags: american-english, british-english, word-usage

I am wondering: Is "Please leave a message after the signal" American English?

You will most often hear "...after the tone" in the UK, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"After the signal" is not used in the U.S.
"after the tone" or "after the beep" is most common.
perhaps "after the signal" is  a literal translation? 
Both "tone" and "beep" could be translated as 'signal'

Comment: Agreed. We'd mostly consider a "signal" to be something that has a visual component.

Comment: If you use this on your voice mail, you'll get a lot of messages like "What signal am I waiting for? You mean the beep or something else?  I guess it has to be the beep unless...  Wait, was that something?  Should I-"